# PATH environment variable not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, path, sudo

When I execute a command on the terminal:

```
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
```

I added in the files: **.bashrc**, **etc/enviroment**, **.profile** and **.bash_profile** the line:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

The error still persists.

When I run the command **echo $PATH** only show:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java:/usr/bin
```

I found this Java PATH in **.bashrc**.

I was able to use **SUDO** and other commands by entering:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

But it is not permanent.

Comment: What's the line that adds `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`?

Comment: Have you tried opening another shell and then checking for the PATH environment if it was set? Changes are not live in the current shell.

Comment: @thatotherguy added a long time ago, don't remember how, did not disrupt the path at the time.

Comment: @timunix yes, even restarted the system, same result.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that there aren't any quotes in your PATH entry. Also you need to export your path at the end.
Write this at the end of your .bashrc and remove your entries in /etc/environment and your  profile files:**

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
export PATH
```

I hope this does the trick for you.

Comment: unfortunately it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Then you should probably ask that question on unix.stackexchange because this isn't the right place. Stackoverflow is about coding. Move your question there and provide them more output details. There are a bunch of Linux administrators. Surely someone will fix your issue there.